# MVVM Обновление данных в viewmodel если обновлены данные в model

Tags: wpf, mvvm

При загрузке файла данные записываются в модель. При этом надо их надо обновить в vm. Как это сделать?

Answer (score 2):

Предполагаю, что вопрос задаётся в контексте WPF. Ответ зависит от степени следования хардкорному MVVM и конкретной задачи, если коротко, то:

1. Реализуйте интерфейс [`INotifyPropertyChanged`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged(v=vs.110).aspx) в модели. В VM реализуйте свойство `Model`, привязку данных осуществляйте через свойство Model модели представления, например `{Binding Model.Title}`. Данные напрямую будут браться из модели и всегда будут актуальны. Минус очевидный - для многих случаев VM будет вырожденной в смысле свойств данных (но все еще сохраняется возможность реализовывать в ней свойства, касающиеся только состояния представления).
2. Реализуйте интерфейс `INotifyPropertyChanged` в модели и модели представления. В VM реализуйте свойство Model и прокси свойства, которые обёртывают свойства модели (дублируя их названия для простоты). Подпишитесь на событие PropertyChanged модели и пробрасывайте событие изменения прокси свойств модели представления при изменении свойств модели.

Например, свойство модели представления:

```
public string Title
{
    get
    {
        return Model.Title;
    }
    set
    {
        Model.Title = value;
        OnPropertyChanged("Title");
    }
}
```

Подписка на событие изменения свойств модели:

```
Model.PropertyChanged += OnModelPropertyChanged;
```

Обработка события и проброс события изменения свойств модели представления:

```
private void OnContentPropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    OnPropertyChanged(e.PropertyName);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Третий пункт в дополнение к вариантам **@dm.dymov**:

3. Если и модель, и вью-модель под вашим полным контролем, и требуется только отобразить данные реализующей INPC модели на вьюхе, то есть вью-модель ничем не дополняет по функциональности модель, то можно отдать вьюхе голые модели. Вью-модель появляется тогда, когда вьюхе от привязываемого объекта требуется больше, чем разумно разместить в модели.

В самых простых программах не грешно объединять в один класс DTO, Model и View-Model. За счёт нарушения SRP можно упростить программу в разы. Разумеется, в сложных программах так делать не надо.

Answer (score 0):

Да в общем-то как угодно.

Дело модели — выставлять данные так, чтобы можно было ими воспользоваться, так, как это модели угодно. А вот дело VM — выставить наружу `INotifyPropertyChanged`, разобраться, как модель информирует о своих изменениях и в каком потоке, подписаться на эти изменения и, если нужно, обновить свои данные (причём сделать это обязательно в UI-потоке).

Таким образом: на модель требования не накладываются, она сообщает об изменениях как ей вздумается. А вот VM должна уже подстраиваться под требования WPF.